# Is there a comprehensive MIME header format reference online somewhere?

Tags: mime

I've looked at probably 100 sites, and haven't found anything.  Some are just lists of mime type values, others references to the RFCs, or more or less direct quotes from them.  The RFCs are impenetrable, and each only reveals one small part of the elephant.

Is there somewhere that gives us a comprehensive picture of the entire elephant (the MIME header), with all the parts attached in their appropriate locations?

Comment: I take it you have seen this one: http://www.mhonarc.org/~ehood/MIME/1521/rfc1521ToC.html

Comment: What makes you think that they are connected? Each type is defined by its own document. What are you trying to do or learn?

Comment: MIME is more than types.

Comment: So something like http://mailformat.dan.info/headers/mime.html but more thorough? Is that the kind of information you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that's moving in the right direction, but maybe 1/10th of what is really needed.

Comment: Apparently such a site doesn't exist.  I suspect it's in part because no one understands the MIME stuff well enough to write one, combined with the fact that, since no one understands it, any "authoritative" reference would be found to disagree with interpretations by several popular web packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to list websites that have helped me on this topic enormously and hope they can help you two. I saved these to my bookmarks over time:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521
- http://www.hunnysoft.com/mime/
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2048
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2049
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/video/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/audio/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/examples/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/message/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/model/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/multipart/index.html
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html

All of these helped me in one way or another and I saved all of them because I will probably need them in the future, hope they help you as much as they did me.

Comment: Funny how other answers are just a link from the large range above

Comment: Well, http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/ covers about half of them, and your honeysoft.com links are just duplicates, since they just link to the same RFCs.

Comment: thats actually untrue, they are not duplicates, every link has different content, things from the same site can be of differing uses

Comment: tbh its better to use a range of websites. Relying on one source is never a good idea

Comment: I'd love to have multiple sources.  But so far as I can tell there isn't even one.

Comment: Well, I'm going to credit this as an "answer", since it appears to be the best answer to an unanswerable question.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html
That is the ONLY link you should need!

EDIT: Answer in the Comments

http://ietf.org/rfc all the text is there, but not very useful because there is other stuff too. So then, go to the index: http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc-index and ctrl+f for MIME. This brings up 113 hits. Go through the title until you see what you are looking for, then reference the number and get the full text

Comment: There a hundred (more likely a thousand) lists of MIME types on the web.  Not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well what do you mean by elephant?
Did you read these links: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt?number=2045      
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt?number=2046
Those are on the main website...

Comment: Neither one (so far as I can tell) mentions Content-Disposition,for instance.

Comment: Yes, I want to know where there's a SINGLE reference that describes all this stuff in a coherent manner.

Comment: http://www.ietf.org/rfc all the text is there, but not very useful because there is other stuff too. So then, go to the index: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc-index and ctrl+f for MIME. This brings up 113 hits. Go through the title until you see what you are looking for, then reference the number and get the full text.

Comment: This is well the most appropriate answer -- You cannot expect all to be listed on a page ! If you want something specific -- you can always check up specifically .

Comment: I don't expect everything on one page, but I'd like something roughly similar to [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) for HTML or any of a dozen sites for SQL.